# Fetch Received By Information Fro This JSON Code In PHP

Tags: php, json

I'm having trouble in fetching `Received By` Details. This is what i tried so far:

JSON Response: https://pastebin.com/Uty460UY

```
$decoder=json_decode($response,true);
foreach($decoder['data']['hits'] as $cltn1){
$caller = $cltn1['_source']['caller_number'];
$pickedby = $cltn1['log_details']['received_by']['name'];
```

This is the JSON response which company is providing us

Comment: What the hell is _Picked By Details_? And what is `$response`? How could anyone answer this?

Comment: I'm sorry but stackoverflow wan't allowing me to paste the response, I pasted it in Pastebin and question is updated. Please check, thanks :)

Comment: `log_details` is an array, so you'd have to iterate through it, or access it via a key, such as `[0]` for the first result. Use `var_dump($cltn1['log_details']);` to see the structure.

Comment: then how i can fetch received_by details in foreach. Can you provide me a code?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A simple `var_dump()` of the array is enough to tell. Anyway, here's your answer.

```
$x = json_decode($json, true);

foreach ($x['data']['hits'] as $key => $val) {
    $receivedBy = $val['_source']['log_details'][0]['received_by'][0];
    var_dump($receivedBy);
}
```

Which you can see here https://3v4l.org/tImqD